# Are there other isomorphisms between the graphs $G$ and $H$?

Tags: graph-theory

[image]
[image]
[image]

$(\theta, \phi)$ defines an isomorphism between $G$ and $H$. Are there other isomorphisms between these two that are not so obvious? The exercise was to find another isomorphism and after a couple of hours I've just noticed I overlooked that switching $d$ and $f$ gives another one...

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to verify that $\theta$ gives the only possible mapping of the vertices ($v_1$ and $y$ are the only vertices of degree 1; $v_2$ and $x$ are the only ones of degree 5; $v_3$ and $u$ are the only vertices with a loop; $v_4$ and $v$ are the only vertices with three neighbors; $v_5$ and $w$ are left over.) So, the only way isomorphisms could differ is in the case of multiple edges between the same vertices, i.e. mapping $e_7 \mapsto d$ or $e_7 \mapsto f$.